# Altium parameter set

Tags: altium, design, schematic

I'm trying to assign Parameter set for one of the DDR3 SDRAM chip pins. For some reason I can't assign parameter to the group of pins.

For example, if I do this way, then the program cannot assign parameter:

[image]

And when I try to do Design>Update from schematic I don't see anything related to parameters

[image]

But if I assign the pins separately, I can see the changes by doing an Design update. Like this:

[image]

[image]

I checked all the settings related to Parameters sets and I still can't make the pins grouped. Maybe someone knows the solution for this problem?

Comment: What happens if you make the parameter box cover the net labels?

Comment: @ThePhoton , when the parameter box is covered the net labels I can not see any affected object when I make an Design update. Looks like nothing would have happened.

Comment: Have you tried asking on discord - a free user-help service for altium problems/solutions?

Comment: Your blanket directive needs to encapsulate the wires, not just touch them. You may want to create small wires off to the side just long enough to attach their corresponding net labels to (to set their nets), and then draw the blanket directive around them.

Comment: @DerStrom8 Thanks! Now it really works :) . I noticed that many unclear problems appeared in the newer one Altium...